# Calling contract function via web3.eth.sendTransaction doesnt work

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, blockchain, greeter

Im learning how Blockchains work and created a private Blockchain to test some things. I deployed the following contract:

```
contract Greeter         
{
    address creator;     
    string greeting;     

    function Greeter(string _greeting) public   
    {
        creator = msg.sender;
        greeting = _greeting;
    }

    function greet() constant returns (string)          
    {
        return greeting;
    }

    function getBlockNumber() constant returns (uint) 
    {                                                   
        return block.number;
    }

    function setGreeting(string _newgreeting) 
    {
        greeting = _newgreeting;
    }


    function kill()
    { 
        if (msg.sender == creator)  
            suicide(creator);       
    }

}
```

Now I tried different methods to call the setter function
I got the instance with using contract address and abi and called

```
instance.setGreeting.sendTransaction(...)
```

This one worked and with `instance.greet()` I got the new greeting.
But then I tried an example from this page https://github.com/ethereumbook/ethereumbook/blob/develop/transactions.asciidoc#invocation
and called

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({from: eth.coinbase, to: contract_address, data: "0x4136862e000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004d794e65774772656574"})
```

where the data is created of the first 4 bytes of the Keccak256 hash of the prototype function `setGreeting(string)` and the String `"MyNewGreet"` encoded to Hex and padded to 32 bytes. The transaction is mined but `instance.greet()` still return the old greeting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you got the function selector wrong. It should be `0xa4136862`. (You're missing the first character, and you included an extra one on the end instead.)

The string is also incorrectly encoded. It should be a 32-byte location of the data (0x20) followed by a 32-byte length (0x0a), followed by the actual data, right-padded to be a multiple of 32 bytes. See https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/abi-spec.html#argument-encoding for the full details.

All together, this is the correct ABI encoding of your function call:

0xa41368620000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a4d794e6577477265657400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000